# Can someone please explain what "var result=1" is doing in this function?

Tags: javascript, return

Can anyone please explain, in plain English, what the "result=1;" is actually doing here?

I know the function doesn't work without it and that even changing it to 0 breaks it, but I don't understand why.

```
var power = function(base, exponent) {
    var result = 1;
    for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
        result *= base;
    return result;
};
```

Comment: if just declared j but not initialize it then it will take default value 'undefined'.That's  why j=1 here

Comment: It's just the way multiplication works ... `*=` means: Multiply the left hand side of the operator by the right hand side and then assign the result to the left hand side variable. For this to work the left hand side needs to be 1 before the first loop

Comment: not writing `var result = 1` will throw an error, while just writing `var result` will make result 'undefined', that's why you are setting it to 1. This function is the exact equivalent of `Math.pow` anyway. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Comment: Oh! Okay! I get it, now. Whatever the result of the multiplication, we are multiplying that by 1! That's why, when I change it to 0, I get a result of 0. Got it! I know this was very, very basic, but it has freed me up. Thank you!

Comment: @user3472810: Katana314's answer below is the correct and deepest explanation below, you should accept his answer.

Comment: If you learn how to program you should have paper and pen ready ... use it to step through your code, line by line, writing down the content of your variables after each step. I think every programmer should do this before using any debugging tools. You learn a lot about how programs work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inside of the loop is taking `result`'s current value, and multiplying it by the `base` (an argument to the function). Since `0 * anything` is 0, and `undefined * anything` is `NaN`, it needs to be set up as `1` first.

3 ^ 0 = 1

3 ^ 1 (or, 3*1) = 3

Answer (score 1):

It is just initialization of the variable.
If you set it to 0 then `result *= base`

which is in fact `result = result * base` will always return 0

Answer (score 0):

It initializes variable `result`, so you can use it later in the for loop. `result *= base;` is equal to `result = result * base;` so there is the usage.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a sum in a loop you start the variable outside the loop and it's value is the only one that will never alter the result. So result = 0 because any number + 0 results that number.

In this case you are doing a multiplication so you inizialise the variable with result = 1 because you can multiply any value for 1 and you will never alter the result

Answer (score 0):

It is setting the initial value of the variable `result` to 1. If you delete it, you are multiplying `base` by nothing and if set to 0, you are multiplying it by 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to calculate the Power of a number.
You need the `result = 1` just in case zero is passed as the exponent of the function; `1` will be the right answer returned, since the `for` loop won't execute.